# Intercept automatic form submit event in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I'm trying to catch a submit request for a form

```
<form action='/post' name='submitform' id="submitform" method='post' class='pure-form'>
<textarea columns="40" rows="4" name='entry[body]' id="statement"></textarea>
<input type='submit' id="submitbutton" name="btnSubmit" value="save" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
</form>
```

using

```
 document.querySelector('#submitform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { /* code */ });
```

which works fine if I click a submit button

but when I call

```
$('#submitform').submit();
```

or

```
document.forms["submitform"].submit();
```

the form submits bypassing my event listener.

Why?

Comment: try using jQuery `$('#submitform').submit(function(e) { return false; });`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('#submitbutton').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Ok, true, but i'd rather intercept the submit() call - is that possible you think?

Comment: It seems that browsers do not support this. See http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2012JanMar/0011.html

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the jquery submit call by providing an event handler along with the submit function.

```
$( "#submitform" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**For more info**
https://api.jquery.com/submit/